# Shopping cart with many input number_field in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a simple one-page shopping cart with Rails and javascript.

I have a database with my ~ 8 products and this is how my shopping page looks like:

```
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
   <% @product.each do |product| %>
       <%= f.number_field(:product, class: "order-list", name: "#{product.name}", data: {price: "#{product.price}"}, value: 0, in: 0..5) %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit "Continue" %>
<% end %>
```

When I click on submit, I am getting this params

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"mkFBHjgsGZ/dwmQ+Ct6HzafLNwDQlVXOVTdsO97IUUrg7PV9HlpdzJa9Iy03I85t0Nx7dUBKuqZfuGmE700fFQ==", "NameofProduct1"=>"0", "NameofProduct2"=>"0", "NameofProduct3"=>"2", "NameofProduct4"=>"1", "NameofProduct5"=>"0", "commit"=>"Continue", "controller"=>"orders", "action"=>"create"}
```

What is the best way to handle similar shopping cart with just input number fields? How to handle the params? On the server side should I loop with all the products, find the name, merge it with the quantity and save it to the database? Is it a good idea to store each of the product as an object in an array?

Also how to deal with the model: to pass it just params with value more than 0? Because I have an access just like "NameofProductxxxx".

In future I'd like to have it DRY - if I will add product I don't want to change the model or the params.

The final page looks like this (apologies for the local language):
Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to setup a proper many to many relation between Order and Product.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :products, through: :line_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items
end

# as in a row on a order form.
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
  has_many :orders, through: :line_items
end
```

You can generate the LineItem model with:

```
rails g model LineItem order:belongs_to product:belongs_to quantity:integer
```

You might want to use a double type for `quantity` if you have to deal with decimal values.

You would then use [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) to create fields to create/update the associated line items at the same time as the order. `fields_for` iterates through the associated records and creates "scoped" inputs:

```
<%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for(:line_items) do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.collection_select(:product_id, Product.all, :id, :name) %>
    <%= ff.label(:quantity) %>
    <%= ff.number_field(:quantity) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Note that you don't have to use a select for the product id - it could just as well be a hidden field.
Submitting the form should result in params hash that looks like this:

```
order: {
  line_items_attributes: [
    {
      product_id: 6,
      quantity: 4
    }
  ]
}
```

Since our Order model `accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items` you would whitelist the params like so:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @order = Order.new
    @order.line_items.new # seeds form with an empty item.
  end

  def create
    @order = Order.create(order_params)
    respond_with(@order)
  end

  def update
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    @order.update(order_params)
    respond_with(@order)
  end

  private
  def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(line_items_attributes: [:product_id, :quantity])
  end
end
```

Displaying the cost per line is the next concern that you need to solve.

Usually you would just do something like:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product

  def total
    product.price * quantity
  end
end
```

---

```
<%= f.fields_for(:line_items) do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.collection_select(:product_id, Product.all, :id, :name) %>
  <%= ff.label(:quantity) %>
  <p><%= ff.object.total if ff.object.persisted? %></p>
<% end %>
```

However if you want to update the total when the user changes the quantity or item you need to implement a AJAX call which is a compete question or tutorial on its own.

Comment: Make sure you read the docs for [`accepts_nested_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) its one of the hardest parts of the Rails core to learn.

Comment: Wow, amazing. Thank you Max!

Comment: Max, can I have extra question? Just thinking.. if I have just a few products with number inputs... is not it easier to do it with single product db & single order db and the shopping cart shows based on javascript - if value of a product will increase, we will show it in the cart... without saving it to db. What is your opinion on it? Pros vs cons?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking - you normally start out with just one database and then scale out if you need more. When it comes to the rest - you can either have it "live-update" so that when the user changes a quantity it sends an `PATCH /orders/:id` update in the background and then refresh the whole form. Or you can just setup a listener that sends an AJAX request to "GET /products/:id" when the user changes the product_id or quantity and changes the displayed price.

Comment: How you do it depends on how you want the user interface to work - personally I have gotten so used to mobile apps that I get annoyed if I have to press "Update" to save my changes. I would encourage you to ask a new question if you are unsure how to do this.

Comment: Thank you Max. What I meant is that I created js file with addEventListener to input elements. If the value of any input element change, it will be stored in js array + calculate total cost of each product * value if value > 0 and will be showing to the user by innerHTML in the shopping cart. Just wondering why I should want to go to the back end if I can make it like this? Security?

Comment: I created a new question as you recommend. Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36134685/rails-shop-with-javascript-shopping-cart-best-way-to-submit-form if you have time...:)